# Hibernate xml -> annonations described by formula

Tags: xml, hibernate, annotations

Is there any possibility to map following xml into annotations?

```
<one-to-one
 name="property"
 class="org.my.app.TargetObject">
 <formula>APP_ID</formula>
 <formula>'Yes'</formula>
</one-to-one>
```

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of Hibernate have @JoinColumnOrFormula. So you could probably map it similar to this:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
  @JoinFormula("APP_ID"),
  @JoinFormula("YES")
})
```